# unable to connect to bugzilla server through SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python-2.7, bugzilla, simplexmlrpcserver

here am getting error like "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed".

```
import SimpleXMLRPCServer
def add(a,b):  
  return a+b
def main():
 server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(("http://10.98.100.119/PTS_RT_CSP_Sprint_Lab/bugzilla",8080))
 server.register_function(add)
 server.register_introspection_functions()
 server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: if i run above code with server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost",8000)), server is running. if i change my bugzilla server_URL end up with "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed"